# Dashboard with CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, dashboard

I need to create a dashboard in SharePoint online.

- Read content from multiples lists
- Use HTML and CSS to style multiple tables

When I work with the SSOM I use this approach:

- Create an ASPX page
- Add CAML, HTML and CSS

Which approach should I use with CSOM? Which kind of page do you recommend to create and where? And how to reference de JS code and where to store this code? I am looking for best practices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be multiple possible way for achieving this, but here I am sharing what I will do if I have to achieve this requirement.

- I will go with JSOM/REST API to fetch the data from list/ multiple
  list
- Write all the business logics to fetch the data into a separate JS
  file. In short, prepare datasource here.
- Upload that JS file in `Style Library/Site Assets/Document Library`
  wherever I want.
- Create a new html page and provide the reference of JS on that page
- Create a new SharePoint page in Site Pages.
- Edit the page from browser
- Add Content Editor WebPart
- Provide the reference of HTML file in the Content Editor WebPart

And you will get the data displayed on the page. And if you want this as a dashboard, then set it as a Welcome page for the site so that it can be opened when someone one the site.

let me know if you find any missing information or you need some more clarification.

**Updates:**

If you don't want to use Content Editor WebPart then just follow the steps:

- Activate the Publishing Features for SharePoint site.
- It will create `Pages` Library automatically.
- Create page in the Page library.
- Edit this page from SharePoint Designer.
- Keep your entire business logic here as you are working with HTML
  page.

***Note:*** Here you can reference your JS file directly into the page. Here you will not need any other HTML page.

Comment: It's very clear. Quite a bit like what I imagined. Are there any alternatives that do not involve using a CEWP?

Comment: Updated the answer with one more approach..

Comment: Which is the best option for you?

Comment: If you ask me then i will choose option with CEWP.. Because it does not require any check in/check out :-P.  While second option will require check in to the page in order to available for all users..